# Drawing dynamic panels C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Good afternoon.
There was a problem with the rendering of dynamically created panel, all panels initially were 100px and I their renders (y + = 100), but now the production has changed a bit, these panels can be of different sizes, and the distance between them actually remains unchanged 100rh ...

Pliz tell me how to make, that they are somehow drawn at equal (10px) distances from each other. Read that you can somehow make a method SetBounds, but did not understand.

http://pastebin.com/TnSuFTti

```
for (int i = data_list.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    Panel panel = new Panel(); //создание блока сообщения и наложение картинки
    panel.Name = i.ToString();
    panel.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(panel_MouseEnter);
    Label textBox_name = new Label();
    Label textBox_date = new Label();
    Label textBox_msg = new Label();
    panel.Width = 308;
    Bitmap btm_msg = new Bitmap(
                Properties.Resources.NotificationCenterWindow_msg_box);
    panel.BackgroundImage = btm_msg;
    panel.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    panel.Location = new Point(5, 5);

    panel.Controls.Add(textBox_date); 
    textBox_date.Name = "textBox_date" + i.ToString();
    textBox_date.Location = new Point(232, 8);
    textBox_date.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(70, 15);
    textBox_date.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    textBox_date.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(72, 15);
    textBox_date.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    textBox_date.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    textBox_date.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;
    textBox_date.ForeColor = SystemColors.ScrollBar;

    panel.Controls.Add(textBox_name); 
    textBox_name.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 15);
    textBox_name.MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(100, 15);
    textBox_name.Location = new Point(5, 8);
    textBox_name.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;
    textBox_name.BackColor = Color.DarkGray;
    textBox_name.ForeColor = SystemColors.ScrollBar;
    panel.Height = textBox_name.Height + 19;
    panel1.Controls.Add(panel);
    panel.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Top;

    y += 100;
}
```

Comment: Include relevant code in your post, I (like others) am unwilling to click on links that provide code that should be included. That being said, your question is still unclear

Comment: sorry, but in all forums don't like when somebody post code...

Comment: @Zuhan Are you the one who marked the favorite icon (the star)? BTW, what is `(x,y)`? Your problem is in fact very simple, you have to calculate the `Location` for each added `Panel`, based on the `Bottom` of the last `added panel`.

Comment: I forgot to write the coordinates here, they have me declared at the beginning of class ...

Comment: @Zuhan on Stack Overflow it is okay to post large amounts of code as long as that code is relevant to the question. For example there would be no need to post an entire project, with all the forms, instead you would make simplified, bare bones version that simply illustrated the issue. Splitting the problem from the rest of your code is actually often a good first step in debugging anyway, as it removes other factors that may interfere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
panel.Location = new Point(5, y);
//.....
y = panel.Bottom + 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just set the position based on the previous panel...

```
// This will put the panel to the right of an existing one
panel_b.Left = panel_a.Left + panel_a.Width + 10;
```

.

```
// This will put the panel below an existing one
panel_b.Top= panel_a.Top+ panel_a.Height+ 10;
```